Chrony NTP: synchronization with an external NTP server in my Docker container works for a few seconds, but after that, synchronization stops working
Time synchronization with an external NTP server in my Docker container works for a few seconds, but after that, synchronization stops working :
logs :
2024-09-08T20:54:15Z chronyd version 4.0 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +NTS +SECHASH +IPV6 -DEBUG)

2024-09-08T20:54:15Z Initial frequency 83333.333 ppm

2024-09-08T20:54:15Z Using right/UTC timezone to obtain leap second data

*2024-09-08T20:54:20Z Selected source 196.200.160.123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org)*
2024-09-08T20:54:20Z System clock wrong by -5318.299142 seconds

2024-09-08T19:25:41Z System clock was stepped by -5318.299142 seconds

2024-09-08T19:25:41Z System clock TAI offset set to 37 seconds

2024-09-08T20:54:45Z Forward time jump detected!
**2024-09-08T20:54:45Z Can't synchronise: no selectable sources**

/etc/chrony/chrony.conf file :
confdir /etc/chrony/conf.d

pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst

sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp

sourcedir /etc/chrony/sources.d


keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys

driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift

ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony


logdir /var/log/chrony

maxupdateskew 100.0

rtcsync


makestep 1 3


leapsectz right/UTC


hm, Linux namespaces, and thus docker containers, do not support "containerized clocks"; all you can have is that you get a monotonic clock (and clock_boottime, but I'm not sure what that would be good for) that you can adjust via /proc/self/timens_offsets.

Hence, I believe running chrony in a container is probably senseless, as that container won't be allowed to change the system-wide clock, and doesn't have it's own. What is it that you want to achieve with this?

im not looking for changing host vm clock, i would just my containers be in sync with external NTP server not Host kernel system.

as said, Linux does not support that.

some time using chrony in containers is uisefull for some cases: like debugging time-related issues, such as expired SSL certificates

again, Linux does not allow containers to have an independent time-of-day clock. That is simply not a feature of Linux. See man time_namespaces.

Okay, but why has my container time changed for only a few seconds?

it hasn't. that's what it detects.

Linux namespaces, and thus docker containers, do not support "containerized clocks"; all you can have is that you get a monotonic clock (and clock_boottime, but I'm not sure what that would be good for) that you can adjust via /proc/self/timens_offsets.
So, what you want to do doesn't work on Linux.
